# error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw, vulkan

I am currently learning Vulkan and I tried to set up a window with GLFW but when I try to call functions from GLFW I get these errors:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsprintf referenced in function __glfwInputError
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf referenced in function __vsscanf_l
error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

```
void startGlfw(){
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(400, 300, "Tutorial", nullptr, nullptr);

}
```

At this point I have no idea why it's not working. I checked several times if I set everything up correctly in VS and remade the project to be sure it's a console application.

Comment: link with `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib`

Comment: I guess I need to add that to additional library directories. where do I find that file?

Comment: this from `<vc_install_dir>\VC\lib`